# Add column containing status to table based on number of occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL table contains two columns: Order and Order Line. Now I would like to add a third column (Status) to my table to indicate whether it's a single or multi line order. If the order number only occurs only once then 'Single line' else 'Multi line'. How can I do this? Thanks!

| Order | Order Line | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 10 | Single line |
| 10001 | 10 | Multi line |
| 10001 | 20 | Multi line |
| 10002 | 10 | Single line |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Also called [Analytics Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or Ordered Analytical Functions):

```
SELECT Order, 
  OrderLine, 
  CASE WHEN COUNT(OrderLine) OVER (PARTITION BY Order) > 1 THEN 'Mult line' ELSE 'Single line' END as Status
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Oof, beat me to it